# zwrite handling of "@" symbol

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

I've been using zwrite to create simple message popups in AIX, and it handles @ symbols weirdly, even when they're strong quoted. I'm running these commands in ksh.

As an example,

```
echo '1 @ 2 @@ 3 @@@ 4 @@@@ 5 @@@@@ 6 @@@@@@'
```

produces the expected output, but

```
zwrite myuserid -m '1 @ 2 @@ 3 @@@ 4 @@@@ 5 @@@@@ 6 @@@@@@'
```

produces a window with

```
1 @ 2 @ 3 @@ 4 @@ 5 @@@ 6 @@@
```

The result is the same using double quotes instead of single quotes.

Does anyone know if there's a way to correctly escape these signs, and why zwrite does this?

Edit: I did try using `\@`, and it gets printed differently depending on how you quote it and how many you put in sequence.

- `zwrite <myuserid> -m \@` yields `@`
- `zwrite <myuserid> -m "\@"` yields `\@`
- `zwrite <myuserid> -m '\@'` yields `\@`
- `zwrite <myuserid> -m \@\@` yields `@`
- `zwrite <myuserid> -m "\@\@"` yields `\@\@`
- `zwrite <myuserid> -m '\@\@'` yields `\@\@`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `zwrite` but did you try `\@`?

Comment: I did. Turns out @ is used for text formatting. For example, sending `I like @(@color(purple) purple), but I don't like @(@color(green) green)` will produce selectively colored text.

Comment: If you did try escaping with a backslash (`\@`), please [edit] and add that to your question. `\ ` is the classic escape character.

Answer (score 1):

I found part of the answer - `@` is used for formatting text. For example,

```
zwrite userid -m 'I like @(@color(purple) purple), but I don't like @(@color(green) green).'
```

will produce a message with selectively colored text.

More information can be found in the [Zephyr documentation](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/doc/izephyr/html/node13.html). That said, I'm still not sure what the escape character is, if there is one.

Comment: From your example, it looks like `@@` gets output as `@`, but if would be nice if the documentation confirmed it.